# How to write text on a image in windows using python opencv2

Tags: python, windows, opencv

I want to put some text on an Image.
I am writing the code as:

```
cv2.putText(image,"Hello World!!!", (x,y), cv2.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 255)
```

It gives ERROR, saying 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX'

**Query**
Can't I use the font type as above? I searched in internet, but found only the syntax related to to Opencv C++ for initFont.
Then I thought of using `putText` to pass the font type as parameter.
But it is not working for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 171):

This code uses cv2.putText to overlay text on an image.  You need NumPy and OpenCV installed.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

# Write some Text

font                   = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
bottomLeftCornerOfText = (10,500)
fontScale              = 1
fontColor              = (255,255,255)
thickness              = 1
lineType               = 2

cv2.putText(img,'Hello World!', 
    bottomLeftCornerOfText, 
    font, 
    fontScale,
    fontColor,
    thickness,
    lineType)

#Display the image
cv2.imshow("img",img)

#Save image
cv2.imwrite("out.jpg", img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: It may be useful to know the size of the written text: `text_width, text_height = cv2.getTextSize(text_description, font, fontScale, lineType)[0]`

Comment: Here `lineType` should be `lineThickness` since that is the parameter list. See: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#puttext

Answer (score 49):

Was `CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX` in cv(1)?
Here's all I have available for cv2 "FONT":

```
FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL
FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX
FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX
FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX
FONT_ITALIC
```

Dropping the 'CV_' seems to work for me.

```
cv2.putText(image,"Hello World!!!", (x,y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 255)
```

Comment: How did you get the list of available fonts?

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson My approach for that is usually just at the Python prompt, like this: `import cv2; [x for x in dir(cv2) if x.startswith('FONT_')]`

Comment: In [471]: [(i,getattr(cv2,i),) for i in dir(cv2) if i.startswith('FONT_')]
Out[471]:
[('FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX', 3),
 ('FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL', 5),
 ('FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX', 2),
 ('FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN', 1),
 ('FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX', 7),
 ('FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX', 6),
 ('FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX', 0),
 ('FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX', 4),
 ('FONT_ITALIC', 16)]

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar problem. I would suggest using the `PIL` library in python as it draws the text in any given font, compared to limited fonts in OpenCV. With PIL you can choose any font installed on your system.

```
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("lena.png")

# Convert to PIL Image
cv2_im_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pil_im = Image.fromarray(cv2_im_rgb)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_im)

# Choose a font
font = ImageFont.truetype("Roboto-Regular.ttf", 50)

# Draw the text
draw.text((0, 0), "Your Text Here", font=font)

# Save the image
cv2_im_processed = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(pil_im), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", cv2_im_processed)
```

### result.png

[image]

Comment: Although your solution apparently works, I think it does not answer the question which specifies it uses Opencv.

Comment: Also, doesn't work out of the box on Ubuntu, which seems to not find the font.

Answer (score 11):

This is indeed a bit of an annoying problem.
For python 2.x.x you use:

```
cv2.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
```

and for Python 3.x.x:

```
cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
```

I recommend using a autocomplete environment(pyscripter or scipy for example). If you lookup example code, make sure they use the same version of Python(if they don't make sure you change the code).

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a really old question but i think i have a solution
In the newer versions of openCV fonts are repesented by a number like this

```
    FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX = 0,
    FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN = 1,
    FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX = 2,
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX = 3,
    FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX = 4,
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL = 5,
    FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX = 6,
    FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX = 7,
    FONT_ITALIC = 16
```

so all you have to do is replace the font name with the corresponding number

```
cv2.putText(image,"Hello World!!!", (x,y), 0, 2, 255)
```

again i know its an old question but it may help someone in the future

Answer (score 4):

I use python 3 and this code below works fine for me.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('lena.jpg',1)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
cv2.putText(image,'Hello There',(0,100),font,2,(255,255,255),3)  #text,coordinate,font,size of text,color,thickness of font

cv2.imshow('image',image)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code with parameter labels

```
def draw_text(self, frame, text, x, y, color=BGR_COMMON['green'], thickness=1.3, size=0.3,):
    if x is not None and y is not None:
        cv2.putText(
            frame, text, (int(x), int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, size, color, thickness)
```

For font name please see another answer in this thread.

Excerpt from answer by @Roeffus

> This is indeed a bit of an annoying problem. For python 2.x.x you use:
>
> cv2.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
> and for Python 3.x.x:
>
> cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

For more see this http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/83399/cv2.putText

Comment: You can use the library PILasOPENCV https://github.com/bunkahle/PILasOPENCV which is a wrapper around common PIL functions but internally only uses OPENCV

Answer (score 1):

You can use cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX instead of cv2.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX in current opencv version

Answer (score -1):

for the example above the solution would look like this:

```
import PILasOPENCV as Image
import PILasOPENCV as ImageDraw
import PILasOPENCV as ImageFont
# from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("lena.jpg")

# Convert to PIL Image
cv2_im_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
pil_im = Image.fromarray(cv2_im_rgb)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(pil_im)

# Choose a font
font = ImageFont.truetype("Roboto-Regular.ttf", 40)

# Draw the text
draw.text((0, 0), "Your Text Here", font=font)

# Save the image
cv2_im_processed = pil_im.getim()
cv2.imshow("cv2_im_processed", cv2_im_processed)
cv2.waitKey()
```