# Put different styles of text in single command Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

How to put different styles of text on image in single command cv2.text()?
Example:
hello **WORLD**

Comment: you mean `cv2.putText`? You can't. OpenCV is not meant to do this sort of things. Use any other library to draw text on your image

Comment: @Miki are you sure? I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615662/how-to-write-text-on-a-image-in-windows-using-python-opencv2) and it seems it is possible.

Comment: It draws text on an image **with the same style**, but **not** different styles of text with a single function call

Comment: I show a way to use different fonts here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697181/2836621

Comment: @Mark as I understand, the OP wants something to basically draw rich text. Something like `putText("hello <strong>WORLD</strong>")`

Comment: @Miki Aha, thank you, I see now. In which case, **Pango** may be an option... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51963371/2836621

Comment: @Miki <strong>, it is simply adding text to the image as it is.

Comment: @sivaram yes obviously. OpenCV doesn't handle rich text. See Mark's link about Pango instead